# Get concrete type from method expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees

If I have an expression in the form of `Expression<Func<Delegate>>` is it possible to determine the *derived* type of the object used to pass in the delegate? Does the expression even contain this information, or is it exclusively representative of the delegate.

A code example should make things clearer.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Sandbox {

    public interface IContract {
        void Method();
    }

    public class Concrete : IContract {
        public void Method() { }
    }

    public class Test {

        private IContract contract = new Concrete();
        private Concrete concrete = new Concrete();

        public static string GetFullMethodName(Expression<Func<Action>> expression) {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
            var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;

            var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Last();
            var methodInfo = (MemberInfo)methodInfoExpression.Value;

            var type = methodInfo.DeclaringType;
            var name = methodInfo.Name;

            return String.Format("{0}.{1}", type, name);
        }

        public Test() {
            var strConcrete = GetFullMethodName(() => concrete.Method); // Sandbox.Concrete.Method
            var strContract = GetFullMethodName(() => contract.Method); // Sandbox.IContract.Method
        }

    }

}
```

Is it possible to make `() => contract.Method` produce

> Sandbox.Concrete.Method

Instead of

> Sandbox.IContract.Method

Can the expression be altered to support this, or would I be forced to pass an instance of the object as a separate parameter in order to determine it's type?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Something to aid with debugging?

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible.

The expression tree is built based on compile-time information, and at compile-time, the method being invoked is the virtual `IContract.Method`. The fact that at runtime, the `Concrete.Method` is actually invoked is irrelevant - that's handled in the virtual dispatch mechanism and the compiler finished its job long before any of this is decided.

The best you can do is try to emulate virtual dispatch yourself. For example, you could try enumerating the interface implementation on the `this` instance at runtime, and if you do find a method that matches the interface, you'd return that. However, this is certainly tricky - you need to be able to perfectly emulate the actual virtual dispatch.

Another tricky point is that the way you're trying to get the value is already broken. For example, in my environment, the `methodInfoExpression` is *not* a `ConstantExpression` - it's a field on a closure type. Your "parsing" is very fragile.

That said, it's also kind of unnecessary and overcomplicated - you're trying to receive an expression that returns an action and "steal" the value of the action out of the expression. There's already a simple way of doing that - pass that argument directly. No need to hide it in an expression tree:

```
public static string GetFullMethodName(Action action)
{
  return string.Format("{0}.{1}", action.Method.DeclaringType.Name, action.Method.Name);
}

var strConcrete = GetFullMethodName(concrete.Method).Dump(); // Sandbox.Concrete.Method
var strContract = GetFullMethodName(contract.Method).Dump(); // Sandbox.Concrete.Method
```

You don't need expressions for things that basic reflection already gives you :)

Comment: I feared as much. With regard to the complexity, a simple `Action` changes the syntax for the caller from `a.Method` to `a.Method()`, a small difference but I'm trying to provide a little syntax sugar (there are variants of this method which accept various inputs/returns which would then need to be provided, although not used)

Comment: @RedTaz No, that would only be needed if you used an expression directly for the delegate (e.g. `Expression<Func<string, int>>`). You do need to supply overloads for all possible signatures - but you have exactly the same problem in your code as well. Those overloads are actually quite easy to handle - just write a simple T4 template and keep all the type arguments generic.

Comment: Ah I see now, yes you're right, it's overly complex! :)